# Set server wide ssl configuration

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, apache-2.4, lets-encrypt

**Background**  I have a simple server with only one site.  I want to force ssl.  I previously did this with a self signed certificate, but now I have got a letsencrypt cert.  I have used the auto set up, but when I access my site it uses the old certificate.

I think my question is similar to: [default apache index.html shows up even though i have a sites-enabled file](https://serverfault.com/questions/690646/default-apache-index-html-shows-up-even-though-i-have-a-sites-enabled-file)

In this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/690668/226403 one of the options is "If you want this as your default/only host, then don't even bother with VirtualHost tags, and apply your configuration at the server level".

**Question** How do I change the server wide configuration?  I think this server wide configuration is what is using the old certificate, but I cannot fathom how to change it?

Thanks!
(My set-up is a Ubuntu VM using apache)

Edit:  In /etc/apache2/ssl there are old .key and .pem files, if I move these **everything** breaks horribly and apache won't start!

**Solution** (For me at least).  Apparently you can set things up in sites-available and in conf-available.  Lets Encrypt automatically sets up sites-available for you, but not conf-available.  I performed a recursive search (using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/finding-all-files-containing-a-text-string-on-linux):
`$ grep -rnw '/etc/apache2/' -e 'SSLCertificateFile'`.  Found the incorrect files in conf-available and rebooted apache: `sudo service apache2 reload`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an existing, working https configuration in `/etc/apache2/ssl` you should only need to change the values for the relevant configuration files to point to the new files supplied by letsencrypt.

For example, example.com files would be stored in

```
/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/
```

The configuration settings you need to change are

```
SSLCertificateFile      /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
```

save the file and restart apache2.